# what do we call this type of data and can we make a reauest using it

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I'm developing a proxy and I came across this problem where I can't resend the request and get the HTML output(ofc I thought about splitting and these things but it won't help later)

```
GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

now I wanna know what do we call this and I wanna know if I can use it without extracting the URL and headers and requesting it

Comment: This is just a transcript of the HTTP protocol for requesting a web page.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know a more technical name of it?

Comment: It's an HTTP request followed by a request header.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution by using socket

```
request="""
GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
"""
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    webserver=re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", request)[0]
    s.connect((webserver, 80))
    s.send(request)
    html = s.recv(1024)
    conn.send(html)
```